# Torsionfree connection on quaternionic manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Does the torsionfree connection (different from Levi Civita) always exist on quaternionic manifold? Where can I find more information about it, something from the very begining? For example, how it looks like on $R^{4n}$

Answer (score 1):

For any connection $\hat{\nabla}$ with torsion $T(X,Y) := \hat{\nabla}_X Y - \hat{\nabla}_Y X - [X,Y]$ you can associate a torsion free connection $\nabla$ by setting
$$
\nabla_X Y := \hat{\nabla}_X Y - \frac{1}{2}T(X,Y)
$$

Indeed,
$$
\begin{align}
\nabla_X Y - \nabla_Y X & = \hat{\nabla}_X Y - \frac{1}{2}T(X,Y) - \hat{\nabla}_Y X + \frac{1}{2}T(Y,X) \\
 & = \hat{\nabla}_X Y - \hat{\nabla}_Y X - \frac{1}{2}T(X,Y) - \frac{1}{2}T(X,Y) \\
& = T(X,Y) - T(X,Y)
\end{align}
$$
since $T(X,Y) = - T(Y,X)$.

There are a lot of connections on well-behaved manifolds...